# Express Server with Static Files through a Dynamic Route

Tags: node.js, express

Here is a basic version of what I'm trying to do. I think I'm probably going at it the wrong way, but it currently serves me a blank page. Is there a better way to dynamically set my static paths? Pretty sure my `app.use` is not working here, but I'm not sure what other direction to go.

```
app.route('/*')
  .all(isAuthenticated)
  .get((req, res, next) => {
    let page_url = url.parse(req.url).pathname
      .replace(/(assets|css|img|js).*/, '');
    let current_dir = path.join(__dirname, `/Pages${page_url}`);
    app.use(`${page_url}`, express.static(current_dir));
    app.set('views', current_dir);
    res.render('index', data);
  });
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There is no sane reason to do this.

Comment: Let's say we have a growing project that could have various levels of nested folders (that align with their url structure). How do I dynamically take the url and route it to the correct path and get the static files?

Comment: But this is what `app.use(express.static('public'));` is for. If Express does not find a route, it looks it up in the /public folder. If you call `example.com/Pages/blub.css`, Express serves the file at `/public/Pages/blub.css`.

Comment: As amberlamps has said, this is clearly wrong code.  For us to help you, you would need to describe exactly what you are trying to accomplish with your static files.

Comment: Okay sure, but if we don't have access to change the routes that these files are being called? For example some projects have static files inside of an assets folder (that would be easy if they were all), but then some of them are split into js, css, and img folders.